# Logging Facebook API Urls with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/).

Is there any way, using the API as written, to see the exact URL that the SDK sends to Facebook? Especially for GET requests (though POST requests would be nice, too -- and seeing what was POSTed as well!)

I want to keep a log of these requests and the success / failure of each call. It would be extremely useful for diagnosing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the uncompiled SDK project to your solution and reference the project rather than a compiled dll, and you can step into the SDK code.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that for previous versions of the SDK. Was just curious if there was a built-in way to do this without having to modify the 3rd party code all the time. Makes updating to the latest more problematic.

Comment: You can try putting a packet sniffer on your webserver's traffic and log those.